# replacing pipe in string

Tags: javascript, regex

Hello I need to remove all occurrences of | from a string. This is what I am doing currently

```
var mystring = "this|is|a|test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/|/g , ","));
```

This gives me this result: ,t,h,i,s,|,i,s,|,a,|,t,e,s,t,
This is not what I want. Why is this not working?

When I try the following, it works for commas.

```
var mystring = "this,is,a,test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/,/g , ":"));
```

This gives me ----> this:is:a:test

Why does it not work for OR and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Escape `|` character.

```js
var mystring = "this|is|a|test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g, ","));
```

Comment: @AvinashPrabhakar To ensure quality answers are promoted to help others, it's considerate and a best practice to accept the answer which you found to work best.

Comment: I do intend to accept this answer but I would have to wait 10 minutes to do so.

Comment: Can't believe three other people beat me to the punch

Answer (score 5):

That's because the pipe character (`|`) is interpreted as the regex-or.

You can however use the pipe char between square brackets, like `[|]`:

```js
var mystring = "this|is|a|test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/[|]/g , ","));
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/oG9zQ5/1)

Square brackets are usually used to write a sequence of characters, but a (positive) side-effect is that most special characters are interpreted literally inside a square bracket environment, as is specified by the [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oG9zQ5/1) explanation next to the regex:

> - `[|]` match a single character present in the list below
>
>   - `|` the **literal** character `|`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to escape the `|`,so if you need this,is,a,test,you need to do
`console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g , ","));`

Answer (score 1):

`|` is a special character, and needs to be escaped with `\`

```js
var mystring = "this|is|a|test";
console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g , ","));
```

Answer (score 1):

Pipe characters must be escaped

```
var mystring = "this|is|a|test"
console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g, ","));
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe symbol is a special charcter. you have to use escape charcter.

```
console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g , ","));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape special characters like "|" with a backslash. Try replacing your last line with this:

```
console.log(mystring.replace(/\|/g , ","));
```

I tested the above in Chrome and it looks to do what you're trying to do.

See the following regarding **Special Characters** for more details on when and how to escape special characters:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp